# Display last 3 calendar year records in PostgreSQL view

Tags: postgresql

I want to display in Postgres View with the records that are greater than 3 calendar years. if today's date is Sep 17th, 2021, then last 3 calendar year is 2018. But I need to consider only the year and not the day/month. So last 3 calendar years is 2018 and I need to display the records from 01/01/2018.

I could get the last 3 years with

```
select * from table1 where datecolumn >= date_part('year', (now() - '3 year'::interval));
```

This query displays the records from Sep 17th, 2018. But I want to display the records from 01/01/2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative that uses just date function avoiding implicit date->double precision->string->date conversion.

```
 select * 
   from table1 
  where datecolumn >= date_trunc('year', (now() - interval '3 years'))::date
```

Comment: This worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Untested on your table obviously, but should work:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   table1 
where 
  datecolumn >= 
  ('01/01/' || extract('year' from current_date))::date - interval '3 years';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the year part from the timestamp/date column as integer and do a simple comparison, like:

```
WITH sample AS (
SELECT UNNEST(
   ARRAY[
      '2016-01-01',
      '2017-12-12',
      '2017-02-02',
      '2018-03-03',
      '2019-04-04',
      '2020-05-05'
   ] )::TIMESTAMP AS datecolumn
)
SELECT datecolumn
  FROM sample
 WHERE DATE_PART('YEAR', datecolumn) >= DATE_PART('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE) - 3;
```

output:

```
     datecolumn      
---------------------
 2018-03-03 00:00:00
 2019-04-04 00:00:00
 2020-05-05 00:00:00
(3 rows)
```